get number of elements after filtering in dplyr using length()
Using mtcars dataset, i want to count how many cars have at least 6 cylinders (cyl).
I use length() after filtering, and get a result of 11
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(
    cyl > 6
  ) %>%
  length()

However the code provided by tutorial is like this, and returns result of 14
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl > 6) %>%
  summarise(n())


by viewing the result directly after filtering, it should also be 14
Now i have learnt that summarise(n()) is better Count number of rows by group using dplyr, and there are more better methods counting after filtering, but i am still confused why my code returns a different result and where the 11 comes from.
Thanks

length() returns number of columns and not rows.

Maybe mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 6) %>% count()?

When applied to a dataframe, length() returns number of columns not rows. But you can pull() variables to see their length(). So, your code counted number of columns instead of rows.
library(dplyr)


# Counts columns
mtcars %>%
        filter(
                cyl > 6
        ) %>%
        length()
#> [1] 11

# Counts rows
mtcars %>%
        filter(cyl > 6) %>%
        summarise(n())
#>   n()
#> 1  14

# Counts rows
mtcars %>%
        filter(
                cyl > 6
        ) %>% 
        pull() %>%
        length()
#> [1] 14

Created on 2024-05-12 with reprex v2.1.0
Or you could have just used count() instead of length()

As pointed by other users, length() returns the number of columns when a dataframe or tibble is piped into it. So we use dim() to get the dimensions of the dataframe then get the first value using [1] since dim() returns the number of rows and the number of columns.
So here's an alternative with minimal change to OP's code.
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(
    cyl > 6
  ) %>%
  {dim(.)[1]}

